# How write unit test for yii2 project

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I read every documents that i found and set up codeception to write unit test for yii2 application.

My project using `mongodb` as database and when i run my unit test to test  save action of my model then i see that `db` component not found.

It's true because i'm using `mongodb` and don't need `db` for sql. anyway when i change my settings to rename `mongodb` database setting to `db` and still using  mongodb connection settings i see error that means yii2 are trying to use SQL activerecord methods.

My test class:

```
namespace common\tests;

use common\models\Developer;
use common\tests\fixtures\DeveloperFixture;
use Faker\Factory;

class DeveloperTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
    /**
     * @var \common\tests\UnitTester
     */
    protected $tester;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function _fixtures()
    {
        return [
            'user' => [
                'class' => DeveloperFixture::class,
                'dataFile' => codecept_data_dir() . 'developer.php'
            ]
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Test to saving user in database.
     * We are using Factory object to create dynamic test cases.
     */
    public function testSaving()
    {
        // use the factory to create a Faker\Generator instance
        $faker = Factory::create();

        $developer = new Developer([
            'name' => $faker->name,
            'description' => $faker->sentences
        ]);

        $this->assertTrue($developer->save(), 'Developer object saved into database.');
    }


    protected function _before()
    {
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }
}
```

My commont/config/test-local.php

```
<?php
return yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/main.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/main-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/test.php',
    [
        'components' => [
            'mongodb' => require_once ('conf.d/test-db.php')
        ],
    ]
);
```

My common/config/conf.d/test-db.php

```
<?php
return
    [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://mongodb/mytestdb', //Using docker container
    ];
```

My fixture class:

```
<?php

namespace common\tests\fixtures;

use yii\mongodb\ActiveFixture;

/**
 * Class Developer
 * Active fixture for using Developer model.
 *
 * @package common\tests\fixtures
 */
class DeveloperFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = \common\models\Developer::class;
}
```

After that i run `vendor/bin/codecept -c core/common run unit models/DeveloperTest`
 I see below error:

```
---------
1) DeveloperTest: Saving
 Test  tests/unit/models/DeveloperTest.php:testSaving

  [yii\base\InvalidConfigException] Failed to instantiate component or class "db".  

#1  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php:139
#2  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:428
#3  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:364
#4  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:156
#5  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php:167
#6  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php:137
#7  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/test/DbFixture.php:41
#8  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php:109
#9  yii\base\BaseObject->__construct
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:375
#1  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:428
#2  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:364
#3  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:156
#4  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php:167
#5  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Instance.php:137
#6  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/test/DbFixture.php:41
#7  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php:109
#8  yii\base\BaseObject->__construct
#9  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:375
#10 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php:156

--

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) DeveloperTest: Saving
 Test  tests/unit/models/DeveloperTest.php:testSaving
Developer object saved into database.
Failed asserting that false is true.
#1  /app/core/common/tests/unit/models/DeveloperTest.php:42
```

And when i change `mongodb` in test-local.php to `db` i see below error log:

```
---------
1) DeveloperTest: Saving
 Test  tests/unit/models/DeveloperTest.php:testSaving

  [yii\base\UnknownMethodException] Calling unknown method: yii\mongodb\Command::checkIntegrity()  

#1  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php:222
#2  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/test/InitDbFixture.php:96
#3  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/test/InitDbFixture.php:78
#4  /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/test/FixtureTrait.php:117
#5  /app/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212
#6  /app/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44

--

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) DeveloperTest: Saving
 Test  tests/unit/models/DeveloperTest.php:testSaving
Developer object saved into database.
Failed asserting that false is true.
#1  /app/core/common/tests/unit/models/DeveloperTest.php:42

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in core of framework module for codeception. You can duplicate database connection in common/config/test-local.php:

```
    'db' => [
        'class' => yii\mongodb\Connection::class,
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app_test_db',
    ],
    'mongodb' => [
        'class' => yii\mongodb\Connection::class,
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app_test_db',
    ],
```